# Perl: User enter a string of characters, as well as a certain regular expression that will be used to search the said string

Tags: regex, perl

```
print "Enter string:\n";
$sentence = <>;
print "Enter the regex to use for search:\n";
$regex = <>;
if ($sentence =~ $regex){
  print "Matching\n";
}
else{
  print "Not matching";
}
print "Match found: ", # This should show the text that is found by the regular expression that is typed by the user.
```

Hello, I am having trouble with my code.
This is what I've been typing in the following fields.
$sentence: The quick fox. $regex: q.*k. The $regex doesn't match with the $sentence. Do I have to convert the $regex? Also, how can I print the matching text in the end? Something like this.

```
Enter string:
The quick fox

Enter the regex to use for search:
q.*k

Matching

Match found: quick
```

Comment: [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp)

Comment: Thank you! I've read about chomp but didn't really understand the use of it. I thought they were always optional.

Comment: You use the chomp will you don't want the trailing newline from the input. If you don't want that newline to be part of the pattern, remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the trailing newline from the input regex:

```
print "Enter string:\n";
$sentence = <>;
chomp $sentence; # remove trailing newline (optional)
print "Enter the regex to use for search:\n";
$regex = <>;
chomp $regex; # remove trailing newline (not optional!!)
if ($sentence =~ $regex){
  print "Matching: $&\n"; # Group 0
}
else {
  print "Not matching\n";
}
```

Comment: Wow! This helped a lot. Thank you. But I want to ask about the $&, where did you get it? Sorry a total newb.

Comment: Perl variables are documented in [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar).